# .text segment encryption in PE32+ executable

Tags: encryption, 64-bit, stub, portable-executable

I am working on `PE` segment encryption(in `C++`). I completed the `PE32 .text` segment encryption. I added `stub` segment to the `PE` that will `decrypt .text` segment at runtime. Used inline assembly in the s`tub` function. But I can't implement the same method in `PE32+ executable(64bit exe)` as it won't support inline assembly. I am able to add the `stub` and `encrypt` the text segment.

Issue is with the `decryption` logic in the `stub`.

I tried adding separate `.asm` files but failed as I am new to assembly language. Please help me with any good documentation or samples on `PE32+ segment encryption`.

This is the code portions:

```
 void (*stub_addr)(void) = stub_fun;// stub_fun is the function to add the 
                                        // decryption logic in .stub segment
unsigned int stub_size = get_stub_size(stub_addr);

//added .stub segment as follows
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)image_addr;
if (dos_header->e_magic != 0x5A4D) 
{
        return NULL;
}
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_headers = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)dos_header +  
            dos_header->e_lfanew);
const int name_max_length = 8;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER last_section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nt_headers) +     
            (nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER new_section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nt_headers) +      
            (nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
memset(new_section, 0, sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
new_section->Characteristics = IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE | 
            IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE;
memcpy(new_section->Name, section_name, name_max_length);
new_section->Misc.VirtualSize = section_size;
new_section->PointerToRawData = align_to_boundary(last_section->PointerToRawData + 
            last_section->SizeOfRawData,
nt_headers->OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
new_section->SizeOfRawData = align_to_boundary(section_size,                
            nt_headers->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
new_section->VirtualAddress = align_to_boundary(last_section->VirtualAddress + 
            last_section->Misc.VirtualSize,
nt_headers->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
nt_headers->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage = new_section->VirtualAddress +     
            new_section->Misc.VirtualSize;
nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections++;

//Changed the stub as Entry Point Encrypted the .text segment
//Now I am confused about how to add the decryption logic in the .stub segment.

#pragma code_seg(".stub")
void stub_fun () {
//Trying in C++ without using assembly language

HANDLE hfile, hfile1;
    unsigned char* pmappedfile, * dummy;
    hfile = CreateFile(NULL, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    hfile1 = CreateFileMapping(hfile, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    pmappedfile = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hfile1, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pimagedosheader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)pmappedfile;
    dummy = (unsigned char*)(pmappedfile + pimagedosheader->e_lfanew);
    IMAGE_FILE_HEADER* pimagefileheader = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER*)(pmappedfile + pimagedosheader->e_lfanew + 4);
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER* pimageoptionalheader = (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER*)((unsigned char*)pimagefileheader + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER));


//Decrypt the .text segment
//How to execute the exe from memory after decryption?
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without assembly language?

Comment: I don't see how you can do it without assembly, especially if you're encrypting the .text section

Comment: Can I do `load PE to virtual memory and decrypt .text segment` in C++ and `continue execution from main()` in assembly? Or the loading PE also should be in assembly? I am totally new to this topic especially assembly. Could you please suggest any good document that explains the encryption method in `PE32+`(`64 bit`)?

Comment: Similar to the method you used for PE32, the mapping of the PE file and everything else can be done in C++. However, the decryption stub needs to be in assembly (although technically you can use a byte array shell code and claim that its not assembly) There isn't much documentation on PE32+ but you can take a look at UPX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will go through the UPX code also.